# Material UI Stack Component is not displaying flex correctly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to implement flex system from material-ui using the Stack component Im faced with a issue. The other half of my screen is displaying another component or blank space and I dont know how to get rid of it.

I'm using the Stack component from material-ui and the normal html iframe tag to build a code editor. Any Idea how I can fix this using Stack?

Screenshot of UI:
[image]

Here is my code:

index.js

```
<Stack sx={{ bgcolor: 'white', pt: 1 }}>
                <TabContext value={value} >

                    <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider', bgcolor: 'white' }}>
                        <TabList onChange={handleChange} >
                            <Tab label="HTML" value="1" />
                            <Tab label="CSS" value="2" />
                            <Tab label="JS" value="3" />
                            <Tab label="Output" value="4" sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' }, mt: 1 }} />
                        </TabList>
                    </Box>

                    {value === '4' ?
                        <Stack sx={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 201px)' }}>
                            <iframe title="result"
                                sandbox="allow-scripts"
                                frameBorder="0"
                                width="100%"
                                srcDoc={iframeDisplay}
                            />
                        </Stack>
                        :
                        <Stack direction="row" sx={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'relative'}}>
                            <Stack sx={{ width: { xs: '100%', md: '50%' }, bgcolor: "white" }}>
                                <TabPanel value={value} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                                    <CodeMirror
                                        value={codeEditor.value}
                                        height={CODE_EDITOR_PROPS.height}
                                        theme={CODE_EDITOR_PROPS.theme}
                                        extensions={codeEditor.extensions}
                                        onChange={onChange}
                                    />
                                </TabPanel>
                            </Stack>
                 <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md:'flex' }, height: 'calc(100vh - 201px)', width: 'calc(50% - 1024px)'}}>
                                <iframe
                                    title="result"
                                    frameBorder="0"
                                    height="calc(100vh - 201px)"
                                    srcDoc={iframeDisplay}
                                />
                            </Box>
                        </Stack>}
                </TabContext>
            </Stack>
```

Comment: set `width="100%"` in `iframe`

Comment: setting the width="100%" on the iframe has made the iframe bigger than the code console. Its no more 50% - 50%

Comment: then set `50%|` instead

Comment: the iframe is getting squashed into a corner with no full width

Comment: @Nifty can you please create a sandbox? A quick advice is to inspect what is constraining your element and doesn't expand, check the parent containers to find it. Then, you have a calculation (width: 'calc(50% - 1024px)) happening, check that as well and for that i would suggest to remove it and rely on the Stack or even the Grid component from MUI. Thanks